# ArcGIS 10.1 using Repast's Agent Analyst Extension - refresh.exe does not work

Tags: arcgis-10.1, agent-analyst

I have installed the agent analyst extension for ArcGis. The refresh.exe, however, does not work. I have made a direct reference to the folder where refresh.exe is.

Comment: "Does not work" does not explain much. Can you elaborate? Does the application crash, does it produce an error message, etc.?

Comment: For the 2nd option, do you post it right in the Refresh folder? I did that and still couldn't get it to go. My directory is C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst\Refresh and then I pasted in the config file. Thanks...

Comment: The option 2 does not work for me, I copied it and pasted it on the notepad and saved as to Refresh.exe.config and then I pasted it on C:Repast3\AgentAnalysis\refresh THen I tried to open Agent Based Analysis in the ArcToolbox but it did not work. Do I need to do something else in order to get this program run on ArcGIS10.1?

Comment: @user18825, have a look at this question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/57563/753

Comment: I have a similar problem, but my version of ArcGIS is 10.2.2.3552. I tried Update 2 option (I don't know how could I do update 1) and it doesn't work. In Refresh.exe.config file I tried to type in newVersion: 10.2.0.0, 10.2.2.0 and my 10.2.2.3552. Only when I put 10.2.0.0 there is no error - when I am clicking Refresh.exe file after changing Refresh.exe.config. Nevertheless there is a problem. When I start my ABM model via agent analyst and there is update action in schedule - program make only one tick and doesn't want to move forward. Do you know what I did wrong? Maybe u have some ready upd

Comment: Hi Melkor, try posting this as your own question and reference this question and what specifically did not work for you. Answers are not the place to be asking questions for your own, albeit related problem. 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 5):

Try building the following C# program with Visual Studio; this should be a drop-in replacement. I am not sure what is wrong with the included refresh.exe but it crashes with a generic APPCRASH on my 10.1 installation:

```cs
using System;
using ESRI.ArcGIS;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework;

namespace Refresh
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop);
            IAppROT appROT = new AppROTClass();
            if (appROT.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < appROT.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (appROT.Item[i] is IMxApplication)
                    {
                        IMxDocument mxDocument = (IMxDocument)appROT.Item[i].Document;
                        mxDocument.ActiveView.Refresh();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** The issue seems to be that at ArcGIS 10.0+, ESRI [no longer provides policy files](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002zp000000) allowing for assembly redirection (so you have to re-compile for each new version). See this [ESRI forum thread](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/41840-ArcGIS-10.1-beta-%28Specific-Version-set-to-false%29-could-not-load-file-or-assembly) for more info. A possible alternative solution to recompiling the program would be to create a [publisher policy file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that redirects the 10.0 assemblies to the 10.1 assemblies.

**Update 2:** Instead of recompiling, you can create an [application configuration file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to [redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the 10.0 assembly dependencies to the 10.1 assemblies. Copy/paste the following into a text editor and save it as `Refresh.exe.config` alongside `Refresh.exe`. Worked for me anyways:

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI" publicKeyToken="8fc3cc631e44ad86" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.1.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto" publicKeyToken="8fc3cc631e44ad86" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.1.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework" publicKeyToken="8fc3cc631e44ad86" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.1.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="ESRI.ArcGIS.System" publicKeyToken="8fc3cc631e44ad86" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.1.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="ESRI.ArcGIS.Version" publicKeyToken="8fc3cc631e44ad86" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.1.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```