# Agent Analyst - Arc 10.5 Refresh has stopped working, config file issue?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, agent-analyst

I'm going through the Agent Analyst EsriPress exercises and cannot get the model to change the ArcGIS agent layer (positions) during a simulation run through the updateDisplay() function within Agent Analyst. I'm using ArcGis 10.5.

I've attempted the fixes described in [Agent Analyst tool interface will not open on ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57563/agent-analyst-tool-interface-will-not-open-on-arcgis-for-desktop) 
but have not had any success getting past exercise 2f (moving agents). Tool will run once and then I get a popup saying "Refresh has stopped working." When I change the Refresh.exe.config file to 10.5.0.0, Refresh appears once. I tried changing it to 10.5.0.6491 (my current version), the refresh error flashes quickly.

Steps Executed:

1. Created Refresh.exe.config file with a text editor and saved it along with Refresh.exe (in C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst\Refresh). The Refresh.exe.config contents are identical to the contents of the configuration file described here [ArcGIS 10.1 using Repast's Agent Analyst Extension - refresh.exe does not work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48655/arcgis-10-1-using-repasts-agent-analyst-extension-refresh-exe-does-not-work).  Replaced newVersion="10.1.0.0" with newVersion="10.5.0.0"
2. Edited the agent_analyst.bat and agent_analyst_run.bat files in the installation folder (C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst) so that the folder paths contain Desktop10.5 in the folder path strings.
3. Edited Environment Variables to make sure that ARC_JAVA, ARC_JAVAW, and ARCOBJECTS_JAR have a fully specified paths entered for each variable.
4. In my Environment Variables, I moved ARC_JAVA (C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\java\jre\bin\java), ARC_JAVAW (C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\java\jre\bin\javaw), ARCOBJECTS_JAR (C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\java\lib\arcobjects.jar), AGENT_ANALYST (C:\Repast 3\Agent Analyst), and AGENT_ANALYST_VOL (C:) from my User Variables to my System Variables.

Comment: What are the precise and detailed steps that you have performed to get to where you are stuck?  All questions here should be standalone and not rely on potential answerers following a tutorial hosted elsewhere.

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem? having the same issue, although with ArcGis 10.1.
Thank you.

Comment: Never got it to work. Sorry. Best of luck!